# Error while running an Android application through device

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

Am using Windows 7 (64-bit) and Eclipse Release 4.2.0 to develop my android App.
After solving a handful of issues finally my device is visible in eclipse (adbdriver.com installed this driver). But now, after running an application am facing the following problems

```
**[2013-12-20 16:44:34 - call1] Android Launch!
[2013-12-20 16:44:34 - call1] adb is running normally.
[2013-12-20 16:44:34 - call1] Performing com.example.call1.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-12-20 16:44:37 - call1] Uploading call1.apk onto device '0123456789ABCDEF'
[2013-12-20 16:44:37 - call1] Installing call1.apk...
[2013-12-20 16:44:38 - call1] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK
[2013-12-20 16:44:38 - call1] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-12-20 16:44:38 - call1] Launch canceled!**
```

What should be done to run the application ?
My device is LENOVO A60+ v2.3.6

Comment: Post your manifest in the question, especially the `uses-sdk` part.

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />        My device is LENOVO A60+ v2.3.6

Comment: change **targetSdkVersion** to 17 and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `sdkVersion` in your project manifest file (`AndroidManifest.xml`).

As for example:
 if you want to be able to launch your app on divices from 
`Android 2.2.x` up to `Android 4.4` you need to change  onto:
`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>`

[Full SDK versions list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Comment: @MeenuShankar You can mark my answer as right(by selecting tick under question score)

Answer (score 0):

This means the version of android of your avd is older than the version being used to compile the code.
Build AVD's (Android Virtual Devices) that is the same as your target API version. Also build an older one for compatibility testing